# Reversing a Number using bitwise shift

Tags: java, numbers, bit-manipulation, reverse

I am trying to find a way to reverse a number **without**

1. Converting it to a string to find the length
2. Reversing the string and parsing it back
3. Running a separate loop to compute the Length

i am currently doing it this way

```
 public static int getReverse(int num){
        int revnum =0;
        for( int i = Integer.toString(num).length() - 1 ; num>0 ; i-- ){
            revnum += num % 10 * Math.pow( 10 , i );
            num /= 10;
        }
        return revnum;        
    }
```

But I would Like to implement the above 3 conditions.

I am looking for a way , possibly using the bit wise shift operators or some other kind of bitwise operation.

Is it possible ? If so how ?

*PS : If 1234 is given as input it should return 4321. I will only be reversing Integers and Longs*

Comment: How would you reverse `10000`? Only `1`? You will loose the "zeros"..

Comment: You are unlikely to find a good way to reverse the decimal representation with bitwise operations.

Comment: *"using bitwise shift"* There is absolutely no bitwise shifting going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
int revnum = 0;
while (num != 0) {
  revnum = revnum * 10 + (num % 10);
  num /= 10;
}
return revnum;
```

The code expects a non-negative input.

This may or may not matter to you, but it's worth noting that `getReverse(getReverse(x))` does not necessarily equal `x` as it won't preserve trailing zeroes.

Comment: Its ok If it doesn't reverse negative numbers , I'll just convert it into positive and reverse it and then convert it back to negative

Comment: I guess `getReverse(getReverse(x))` won't be much of a problem now , but if it does I might have to rethink what I am using this function for. I think I will be getting the same problem even with the previous  implementation

Comment: @gautham5678: That's correct: this is a feature of the function's signature (`int`->`int`) rather than of this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It handles negative numbers as well.

```
public int getReverse(int num){
   int rst=0;
   int sign;
   sign=num>0?1:-1;

   num*=sign;
   while(num>0){
      int lastNum = num%10;
      rst=rst*10+lastNum
      num=num/10;
   }
   return rst*sign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is not at all considered in any of the solutions.

For eg: if the input is `-2147483647` or `2147483647` the o/p will be `1126087180` and `-1126087180` respectively.

Please try the below solutions where both the conditions are handled, so if at any point of time the number is going beyond the boundary conditions i.e., `INPUT_VALUE > Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `INPUT_VALUE < Integer.MIN_VALUE` it would return `0`

```
class ReversingIntegerNumber {
    
    public int reverse(int originalNum) {
        boolean originalIsNegative = originalNum > 0 ? false : true;
        int reverseNum = 0;
        int modValue;
        originalNum = Math.abs(originalNum);
        while(originalNum != 0) {
            modValue = originalNum % 10;
            if(reverseNum > (Integer.MAX_VALUE - modValue)/10) {
                return 0;
            }
            reverseNum = (reverseNum * 10) + modValue;
            originalNum /= 10;
        }
        return originalIsNegative ? -1 * reverseNum : reverseNum;
    }
}
```