# How to swap digits from a integer in Java using bitwise operator?

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is swapping the numbers, for example 27 to 72. I tried the code below without any luck.

```
static int reverse(int a){
    int r = 0x0FF & a;
    r <<= 4; a >>= 4;
    r |= 0x0FF & a;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: That would be extremely difficult as the internal representation is a binary number but you want to swap decimal digits.

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar This is about swapping decimal digits in a number, not about swapping the values of two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

int are on 32 bits in java (binary), your example deals with 2 decimal digits.

You can not use binary operator on decimal number: each time you shift left, you multiple by 2 (not by 10)

try modulo operator (%) and division, with 10

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
public class Swap{
    public static int getSwap(int num) {
        int rst = 0;
        int sign;
        sign = num > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        num *= sign;
        while (num > 0) {
            int lastNum = num % 10;
            rst = rst * 10 + lastNum;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        return rst * sign;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 123456;
        System.out.println("Output: " + getSwap(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: You cribbed this reverse function from this submission (this one or another like it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472824/reversing-a-number-using-bitwise-shift

without changing any of the variables or mentioning where you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

Using bitwise this cannot be done. Decimal and binary do not convert this way.

This can be done with radices like 2 (binary) and 16 (hexadecimal) (or any other 2 radices where one is the power of the other) as every 4 digits binary correspond with 1 digit hexadecimal. There is no such relation between binary and decimal.