# Reverse a number using bitwise operations only

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, reverse, bitwise-operators

**reverse a given number only using bitwise operation**
e.g.:
*input:*   4532
*output :* 2354
I'm not able to think of any bitwise operations to tackle this question.Any solution/assistance would be of great help.
The division and modulo by 10 needs to be performed using bitwise operations only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing a Number using bitwise shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472824/reversing-a-number-using-bitwise-shift)

Comment: Are you sure you need to reverse the number in **base 10** (as opposed to **binary**) using bitwise (as opposed to basic arithmetic) operations? I'm pretty sure there is no elegant way of doing that.

Comment: Does "only using bitwise operation" mean not using for, while, if,  ... ?
please explain what does it mean?

Comment: You *can* do it with bitwise operations, but you need to implement division_by_10_with_remainder using shift/compare/subtract. All of those can be done in bitwise fashion, and we'll see you next month ;)

Comment: The division and modulo by 10 needs to be performed using bitwise operations only.I'm looking for a logic to do that.

Comment: This could be a very interesting number theory question because there's a easy way of calculating modulo 10 from power of 2.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble and https://www.cypress.com/file/42131/download

Answer (score 0):

there's no efficient way of reversing a number using only bitwise operators (mostly shift operators). But we can use BCD conversion to convert the integer to BCD and then reverse using shift operators. So after BCD conversion we can shift every set of 4 bits (representing a digit ranging from 0-9) step wise in the opposite order, to get the reversed Number in BCD format.